# Insert values into JWPlayer setup 'file' source from database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, jwplayer, playlist

Another JWPlayer question; is it possible to instead of hard-coding a URL source for JWPlayer, use an array of URL's from an SQL database?

```
 jwplayer("mainplayer").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO7kCUjUaUE"
        }],
            primary:"flash",
            autostart: true,
    });
```

The above script shows the hard-coding of URL implementation.

```
<?php

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "USER", "PASSWORD")
or die ("Cannot Connect to MYSQL");

mysql_select_db("DATABASENAME", $conn)
or die ("Cannot Connect to the Database");

$id = $_GET['song_id'];
$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music WHERE id='$id'"));

?>

 jwplayer("mainplayer").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "<?php echo $data['URL'] ?>"
        }],
            primary:"flash",
            autostart: true,
    });
```

Would JWPlayer support the use of an array of URL's gathered in this way for a single player and play them consecutively? Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
file: "<?php echo $data['URL'] ?>"
```

To:

```
file: "<?php echo $data['URL'] ?>",
type: "mp4"
```

So the full thing would be:

```
jwplayer("mainplayer").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "<?php echo $data['URL'] ?>",
            type: "mp4"
        }],
            primary:"flash",
            autostart: true
    });
```